# Poisson mean time - why do the signs flip?

Tags: poisson-distribution, means

I was doing an example, and got the gist of the answer, but not the arithmetic.

Cabs leave with a group of passengers (1, 2, or 3) at rate λ = 10 (per hour). The question wants to know what the mean time is until one taxicab of each type has left.

- There's a 60% chance of a 1-passenger group
- 30% chance of a 2-passenger group
- 10% chance of a 3-passenger group

The answer multiplies the probabilities that at least one car of each group has left (which is $1- prob(0)$ for each type) which makes sense. But after multiplying the parenthesis out, he removes the 1 and reverses all the signs for the mean integral. I'm a little confused - how can he move it to the other side of the equation without the $1$ remaining?

[image: Textbook Answer]

Comment: If $X$ is a non-negative random variable then $\mathbb E[X] = \int\limits_0^\infty S(x) \,dx =  \int\limits_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>x) \,dx = \int\limits_0^\infty \left(1-\mathbb P(X\le x)\right) \,dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minor but unrelated typographical error in the solution.  It should read:

> The probability of at least one taxicab of each type by time $t$ is: $$(1 - e^{-6t})(1 - e^{-3t})(1 - e^{-t}) = 1 - e^{-6\color{red}{t}} - e^{-3t} - e^{-t} + e^{-9t} + e^{-7t} + e^{-4t} - e^{-10t}.$$

That said, the solution does a poor job of explaining *why* these things are true.  A more complete reasoning might be as follows:

The expected time it takes for at least one taxicab of each type to have left is equal to $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \int_{x=0}^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^\infty S_X(x) \, dx, \tag{1}$$ where $X$ is the random variable that measures the desired event time, $f_X$ is the probability density function of $X$, and $S_X = 1 - F_X = \Pr[X > x]$ is the *survival function* of the random event time.  This identity $(1)$ holds when $X$ is a continuous random variable with nonnegative support.

In turn, we observe that $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = \Pr[X_1 \le x]\Pr[X_2 \le x]\Pr[X_3 \le x], \tag{2}$$ where $X_i$ is the first departure time of a taxicab with $i$ passengers.  This is because in order for all three types to have had at least one departure up to time $x$, each type must have had their first cab departing up to time $x$.  This leads to the first equation in the solution.

Now we see how the expectation calculation works:  we simply write $$S_X(x) = 1 - F_X(x) = e^{-6t} + e^{-3t} + e^{-t} - e^{-9t} - e^{-7t} - e^{-4t} + e^{-10t},$$ then integrate term by term.

Comment: Thank you - is there any specific reason why integrating the survival function leads to the mean? There may be a strictly mathematical proof but in terms of intuitive thinking I'm struggling to understand that here. I'd think we'd want the total area under the curve [(F(x), rather than S(x)]